# illegal string offset PHP

Tags: php, array, foreach

Tengo un array y quiero imprimir sus valores dentro de una tabla. Cuando leo el array con un foreach me genera varias  y solo debería ser 1.
Usé is_array para comprobar que realmente sea un array y efectivamente lo es.

Si hago un print_r a mi variable ($arr) me devuelve esto:

```
Array ( [id] => 149 [ejecucion] => 3 [cuenta] => 77 [telefono] => 22505555 [tipo] => A [meses] => 1 [dias] => 0 [factura] => 0 [total] => 84.98 [recopilado] => 84.98 [aplica] => NO )
```

Pero cuando hago el foreach:

```
<?php foreach ($arr as $test): ?> 
    <tr>
        <td class="center"><?php echo $test['id'];?></td>
        <td class="center"><?php echo $test['ejecucion'];?></td>
        <td class="center"><?php echo $test['cuenta'];?></td>
        <td class="center"><?= $test['telefono']; ?></td>
        <td class="center"><?php echo $test['tipo'];?></td>
        <td class="center"><?php echo $test['meses'];?></td>
        <td class="center"><?php echo $test['dias'];?></td>
        <td class="center"><?php echo $test['factura'];?></td>
        <td class="center"><?php echo $test['total'];?></td>
        <td class="center"><?php echo $test['recopilado'];?></td>
        <td class="center"><?php echo $test['aplica'];?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Esto es lo que me imprime en la tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien sabe qué podría estar haciendo mal?

Comment: Ese array solo contiene claves y sus valores, no otros array. No hay nada que recorrer allí. Lo puedes usar directamente con $arr['id'], $arr['ejecucion'], etc

Comment: "Si hago un print_r a mi variable..." a cual le haces `print_r`? a `$arr`? o a `$test`?

Comment: Hola @masterguru! Tenés razón, pero ese es para ese caso en específico, suponiendo que venga más de 1 array, si tendría que usar el foreach... Los array vienen de un JSON que convierto usando json_decode. Hay alguna manera en la que me funcione el foreach independientemente venga 1 o más arrays?

Comment: Hola @Pipe! El print_r es a $arr, ahora lo corrijo!

Comment: Entonces como te dice masterguru, ahi está el problema.... `$arr` no es un `array`, es un `"objeto"` que solo tiene propiedades, no es un `array` de objetos. Es decír, `$arr` es un único elemento

Comment: Sisi, por eso le decía que eso era para este ejemplo puntual. El problema está en que la API que consulta puede devolverme 1 objeto o una lista de objetos, entonces por eso estaba tratando de usar el foreach

Comment: Muéstranos el json con un elemento y con varios para que podamos jugar con ellos y darte una respuesta más acertada. A ciegas o sin un escenario más concreto podemos equivocarnos facilmente y presuponer cosas que no son.

Comment: En lugar de `print_r($arr);` pon un `var_dump($arr);` así verás la estructura completa y de qué tipo es cada cosa. Puede que los datos estén anidados y por eso no funcione como esperas.

Comment: Para imprimir los valores del objeto debe ser mediante el indicador y valor, así: **echo $test -> id;**, **echo $test -> ejecucion;** etc. Agrega tu código completo de PHP para poder ayudarte mejor.